# Do I get the same splits if I use the same random state in 2 different cross validations?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation, training-data

I am working on a machine learning classification prblem where the dataset is imbalanced.  I am examining how different actions can affect the model performance and at the moment i am working with an SVM.

One of the actions that i want to examine is how oversampling can improve or not my SVM's performance.

So, i am using two different StratifiedKFold cases.  One without oversampling, and one with oversampling. Both of those cases are initialized like this:

```
kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=1)
```

The results that i got from both of them are extremely similar to each other.  Does the usage of the same random_state number create the same splits for both cases?

Comment: Yes, if of course the *size* of your dataset is also the same in both cases. But is this the case here? Don't you change the actual size of the dataset when you oversample and undersample?

Comment: Ι do the sampling after the split